# After posting a JSON with postForObject method I get "415 Unsupported Media Type" error

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have a backend server with my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rsrv")
public class ReservationController {
    @Autowired
    private ReservationService service;
    @Autowired
    private ReservationMapper mapper;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, value = "createReservation")
    public void createReservation(@RequestBody ReservationDto reservationDto) {
        service.saveReservation(mapper.mapToReservation(reservationDto));
    } 
    //  + other methods
}
```

as well as frontend that communicates with the backend through HTTP requests. This is some config:

```
@Component
public class ApiClient {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiClient.class);
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Value("${api.endpoint}")
    private String baseEndpoint;

    private URI createReservationURI(LocalDateTime date, Long patientId, Long doctorId) {
        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseEndpoint + "/rsrv/createReservation")
                .queryParam("id", getReservations().size() + 1000)
                .queryParam("time", LocalDateTime.now())
                .queryParam("patientId", getReservations().size() + 1001)
                .queryParam("doctorId", getReservations().size() + 1002)
                .build().encode().toUri();
    }

    public void createReservation(ReservationDto reservationDto) {
        try {
            restTemplate.postForObject(createReservationURI(reservationDto.getTime(), 
                                                            reservationDto.getPatientId(), 
                                                            reservationDto.getDoctorId()),
                                                            null, 
                                                            CreatedReservationDto.class);
            System.out.println("Reservation added!");
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            System.out.println("Reservation hasn't been added!");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to work this thing out and in the meantime I created a separate class (which is pretty much a clone of the original one and is actually used above in the postForObject method):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CreatedReservationDto {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;
    @JsonProperty("time")
    private LocalDateTime time;
    @JsonProperty("patientId")
    private Long patientId;
    @JsonProperty("doctorId")
    private Long doctorId;

    public CreatedReservationDto(Long id, LocalDateTime time, Long patientId, Long doctorId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.time = time;
        this.patientId = patientId;
        this.doctorId = doctorId;
    }

    public CreatedReservationDto() {
    }
    // + getters and setters
```

The createReservation method still doesn't work, I've searched for an answer and it seems that the request itself isn't wrong but the server side isn't just accepting JSON data but I have no idea how to do so. Any help?

I'll include logs: https://pastebin.com/S9jndvEa

Comment: You aren't posting JSON, you are just posting regular parameters. So either your server is wrong (excepting JSON where it shouldn't) or you client is wrong (sending params where it should send JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is expecting a body(JSON format) instead of URL parameters.

A solution for sending a POST request with the desire values would be like:

```
    final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    final CreatedReservationDto createdReservationDto = new 
    CreatedReservationDto("idValue","timeValue","patientValue","doctorValue");

    final HttpEntity<String> body = new HttpEntity<> 
    (gson.toJson(createdReservationDto), httpHeaders);
           
    final URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseEndpoint + 
     "/rsrv/createReservation").build().encode().toUri();
    
    final ResponseEntity<T> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, 
       HttpMethod.POST, body, ConsumedObject.class);
```

Take into account that `ConsumedObject.class` would be the class of the expected response in case of your server is retrieving a response for the POST request.